# Why Mongoose default value not applied in existing model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongoose-schema

I had a mongoose schema like below:

```
const orderSchema = new Schema({
    orderBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user', required: true },
    items: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'cart', required: true },
    ...
)}
```

I have added some data in the database using this schema. After a few days I added a new field like below:

```
prepareTime: { Type: Number, default:  0 }
```

After adding this field, I updated all the existing documents with value prepareTime:0

Now, when I save a new document, the **prepareTime field with default value 0 is not being saved**. How to achieve this functionality?

Comment: There are multiple ways of saving a new document, some will not set the default value. Could you include the code that shows how you save a new document?

Comment: @thammada.ts I have solved the problem. There was a typo in my code :(. Thanks for the comment. Do you know how to delete this question ?